# Struggling To Query Using getDocuments() in Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the first time I am using a Firestore Query and I'm struggling to parse the data. I normally use the same setup when I get documents (which works), but when I attach it to a query it does not work.

I am trying to query the database for the shop most visited, so I can later set it as favourite.

My Code:

```
func findFavouriteShop(completed: @escaping ([String]) -> Void)
{
    // Variables
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
    var dummyDetails = [String]()
    // References
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let groupCollectionRef = String("visits-" + userID! )
    
    // Query the database for the document with the most counts
    dispatch.enter()
    db.collectionGroup(groupCollectionRef).order(by: "count", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(err)")
        }
        else {
            print(snapshot)
            guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
            
            for document in snap.documents {
                
                let data = document.data()
                
                // Start Assignments
                let shopName = data["shopName"] as? String
                let count = data["count"] as? String
                // Append the dummy array
                dummyDetails.append(shopName!)
                dummyDetails.append(count!)
         }
        dispatch.leave()
    }
    dispatch.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    print("USER number of documents appended: \(dummyDetails.count)")
    completed(dummyDetails)}
    )
}
```

Using Print statements it seems as if the guard statement kicks the function out. The processor does not reach the for-loop to do the assignments. When I print the snapshot it returns an empty array.

I am sure I have used the wrong notation, but I'm just not sure where.

Comment: Remove the orderBy() and limit() and see if you can get any documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to comment on, such as your choice of collection groups over collections (maybe that's what you need), why you limit the results to one document but feel the need to query a collection, the naming of your collections (seems odd), the query to get multiple shops but creating a function that only returns a single shop, using a string for a count property that should probably be an integer, and using a string array to return multiple components of a single shop instead of using a custom type.

That said, I think this should get you in the right direction. I've created a custom type to show you how I'd start this process but there's a lot more work to be done to get this where you need it to be. But this is a good starting point. Also, there was no need for a dispatch group since you weren't doing any additional async work in the document parsing.

```
class Shop {
    let name: String // constant
    var count: Int // variable
    
    init(name: String, count: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
    }
}

func findFavouriteShops(completion: @escaping (_ shops: [Shop]?) -> Void) {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    var temp = [Shop]()
    
    Firestore.firestore().collection("visits-\(userID)").order(by: "count", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        for doc in snapshot.documents {
            if let name = doc.get("shopName") as? String,
                let count = doc.get("count") as? String {
                let shop = Shop(name: name, count: count)
                temp.append(Shop)
            }
        }
        completion(temp)
    }
}
```

You can return a `Result` type in this completion handler but for this example I opted for an optional array of `Shop` types (just to demonstrate flexibility). If the method returns `nil` then there was an error, otherwise there are either shops in the array or there aren't. I also don't know if you're looking for a single shop or multiple shops because in some of your code it appeared you wanted one and in other parts of your code it appeared you wanted multiple.

```
findFavouriteShops { (shops) in
    if let shops = shops {
        if shops.isEmpty {
            print("no error but no shops found")
        } else {
            print("shops found")
        }
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
}
```